# How to set only the modified weights for each convolutional layers?

Tags: deep-learning, python, keras

I am currently doing some experiments on modifying the weights and not of the bias for each convolutional layers of a model.

For each of the layers of the model, I used `layer.get_weights()[0]` to get the weights. After modifying the value of the weights for that particular layer I wanted to set the weights back to the corresponding layer.

I wanted to use the `set_weights()` method for that purpose, but however, it takes input both weights and bias, so I could not achieve that. What is the simplest method to set the weight values back to the layers of the model keeping the bias the same as it is?.

I am just a beginner and if the question is not appropriate kindly give me some suggestions and ideas.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! This question is off-topic here because this is just a programming issue. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @nbro Thanks for the correction and responding to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layer.get_weights()` returns list of numpy arrays. Element 0 is weights, element 1 - biases. Actually, I don't remember and can't check it right now, can this list contain something else, but it is not important in your situation, I guess.

So you can do something like:

```
params = layer.get_weights()
weights = params[0]
biases = params[1]
my_weights = <your modifications>
layer.set_weights([my_weights, biases])
```

Comment: I did the same. Thanks.